# Help to compose regular expression

Tags: regex, text, erlang

I have folowing string: `user1 fam <user@example.com>, user2 fam <user2@example.com>, ...`

How can i get mail address from this string with regular expression. I need in output list of mail address

```
user@example.com
uesr2@example.com
```

I try:

```
<.*>
```

But it's ouput with < >:

```
   <user@example.com>
   <uesr2@example.com>
```

Thank you.

p.s. Thank you @xanatos for comment, I use Erlang

Comment: You should ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS write the language you are using, when asking for Regex (well, unless you are asking about comparison between many languages :-) ). There are more implementations of Regex than stars in the sky or grain of sands on the Earth. :-)

Comment: You may consider not using regex's for it at all. The parse is rather simple if you define the state machine directly in Erlang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use the option `ungreedy` so that it only matches the individual bracket pairs.
- `global` so that you can get all the matches.
- and you need `{capture, all_but_first, list}` so that you get the actual values (`list` can also be `binary` if you prefer binary results). `all_but_first` tells `re` to not return the whole match (which would include `<>`), just the group.

Result:

```
1> S.
"user1 fam <user@example.com>, user2 fam <user2@example.com>, "
2> re:run(S, "<(.+)>", [ungreedy, global, {capture, all_but_first, list}]).
{match,[["user@example.com"],["user2@example.com"]]}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the other have said, but to make it faster:

```
<([^>]*)>
```

In this way the Regex won't have to backtrack (with the other Regexes suggested, the Regex will match all the string and then will begin to rollback to find a `>`)

I'll add that, for historical reasons, there are small differences between the `.` and, for example `[\s\S]`. Both catch all the characters EXCEPT the `\n`. The first one (`.`) doesn't catch it. So by using the `[^>]` you are catching the `\n`, but this shouldn't be a problem for what you are doing. http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Just to be complete, because it's a problem that often happens, there is another variant:

```
<((?:(?!>).)*)>
```

(you can substitute the `.` with `[\s\S]` if you want, or use the SingleLine option if your language supports it, to make the `.` behave in a different way). The point here is that the "stop" expression can be longer than one character. Instead of (?!>) you could have inserted `(?!%%)` and it would have stopped at `%%`. BUT I'm not sure this variant work with Erlang (I hadn't noticed the new Tag... It wasn't there when I orginally read the question and I'm not an Erlang programmer... And it seems at least two Erlang programmers have different opinions on the argument :-) )

Comment: This isn't just the fastest way, it's the **only** way (unless you choose to specify a whitelist of all the characters it should match).

Comment: I meant `<([^>]*)>`.  When I wrote that comment, there was the only the one regex in the answer.  By the way, Erlang's regex flavor doesn't support lookaheads, so your second offering won't work.

Comment: @Alan Yes, Erlang does support lookaheads: [re manual page](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html)

Comment: @Alan The `<(.*?)>` should work correctly, so I still don't see how the `[^>]` is the **only** way (even in bold :-) )

Comment: Well how about that!  Guess I was looking at outdated docs; my bad.  (It does say on that page that the `re` module replaces Erlang's native regex support.)  So yes, both the lookahead version and the reluctant quantifier should work.  But `<([^>]*)>` is still better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use groups. See your regex engine's documentation for more details.

```
>>> re.findall('<(.*?)>', 'user1 fam <user@example.com>, user2 fam <user2@example.com>, ...')
['user@example.com', 'user2@example.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and use `<([^>]*)>` which is about as fast as it can get and works for most versions of regular expressions. This is faster as it never has to backtrack while using `<(.*?)>` *will* cause backtracking.